# What's the fastest way to perform SQL functions (select, insert, update) in VBA on an SQL server database?

Tags: sql-server, vba

I don't know between ADO, DAO and DLookUps and such. Does anyone know?

Comment: The speed will depend much more on table structure and data than on the method you'll use to interact with the database. From the data you gave us, I'd say it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that the application bottleneck is usually the actual SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE on the DB and not how the application calls it.  if you are worrying about speed make sure you have well designed tables and indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding DAO vs ADO, I'm not sure about a difference in performance but there is a difference in available functionality.

There is a microsoft article showing the differences in a nice table. [Choosing ADO or DAO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164825%28office.10%29.aspx).

It also states:

*"In particular, ADO is a good choice if you are developing an Access database solution that will later be upgraded to SQL Server — you can write your ADO code to minimize the number of changes that will be required to work against a SQL Server database. In addition, ADO is a good choice for developing new data access components that work with SQL Server, multidimensional data, and Web applications."*

Seems like ADO might be the way to go.

I don't know anything about DLookUps though.